# Morphology with OpenCV on Xarray data array is shifting image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, python-xarray

I am having an issue using the morphology functions in OpenCV on xarray data with python.

I have generated a list of binary xarray datarrays (I understand that I probably should make these just another dimension of the dataset, but I haven't gotten there yet).

I am trying to run morphological closing on this data. In the code snippet below, I extract the actual data from the datarray as a numpy array, then try to run the closing on that. My understanding of OpenCV is that when it reads an image in, it essentially translates it into a numpy array anyway, so I thought this might work. I should mention, the data is originally a geotiff, and I am reading it in using rioxarray, if that makes a difference.

Essentially, what seems to be happening is that the data is being shifted by the size of the kernel for each iteration. I have confirmed this by reading the same slice of the data in the array before and after running the closing operation. It also throws an error that "Axis Limits cannot be NaN or Inf". The output numpy array is the same size as the original, but parts of it have been cut off in one corner, and the other corner, it appears that a No Data  value has been added(?) (value is -1.798e+308).

I am not sure why this is doing this. When I read an image in using imread, the same process seems to work just fine from what I can tell. I also cannot tell if the closing operation is even doing what it is supposed to be doing either. First glance, it only seems like it is shifting it. Code and image below.

```
import rioxarray as rxr
import xarray as xr
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

kSize = 15 #Kernel size
iters = 2 #number of iterations

#Binary list is a list of several binary images generated using xarray.where function
binaryCopy = binaryList[0].copy() #Copy one datarray from list of datarrays...prob should just put this all into one xr dataset, but oh well
inAttrs = binaryCopy.attrs.copy() #Copy attributes to read back in at the end
inDims = binaryCopy.dims
inCoords = binaryCopy.coords

kern = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(kSize,kSize)) #Create square kernel

print(binaryCopy.data.shape) #Print shape of data array (appears to just be a numpy array)

#I had tried this v first, but it did not work, so I tried the steps individually...same issue
#closed = cv.morphologyEx(binaryCopy.data, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kern)

dilated = cv.dilate(binaryCopy.data, kern, iters)
closed = cv.erode(dilated, kern, iters)

newBinaryArray= xr.DataArray(closed,
                        coords=inCoords, 
                        dims=inDims,
                        attrs=inAttrs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharey=True)

#Plot the original first
binaryList[0].plot(ax=ax[0])                           
#Plot the closed data
newBinaryArray.plot(ax=ax[1])
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15,8)
```

[Before (left) and after (right) I run morphological closing. Notice the blue bar on the bottom and left of the image to right. This appears to be a no data value (-1.798e+308)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfFQi.png)

Comment: Ok, so it looks like when I added borderType=cv.BORDER_REFLECT (see here:[link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5)) as an argument to the morphologEx function (I just did it with that one instead of doing dilation and erosion), that worked (or at least helped). There still appears to be an offset in the data, but I don't get the same errors as before.

Comment: I may have solved it. It seems that setting the anchor argument to  anchor=(0, 0) prevents it from shifting. The border type argument in my previous comment just prevented the no data value from being inserted into the extra strip.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like my issue was the anchor. If you set argument anchor=(0,0), that seems to prevent the shift in the data. (I thought this should be (-1,-1) since other places on the internet seem to indicate that puts the anchor in the middle, but the (0,0) appears to work better for me.

Also, when I added borderType=cv.BORDER_REPLICATE (see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5)) as an argument to the morphologEx function (I just did it with that one instead of doing dilation and erosion), that prevented the extra strip that was inserted when the data was shifted from being an enormous "No Data" value and uses the data value at the border.